# How to use CancellationSignal in sqlite Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to cancel a long running Android sqlite query when a user asks to do so.

Looking around I've found:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CancellationSignal.html

and:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Shows several methods (query, raw query) which can make use of the CancellationSignal.

I can't find any examples of this being used however, and I don't understand how to use it or what the effects of this might be.  I'm pretty sure I can figure the first one out, but the second one worries me.

Answer (score 0):

You use it by having such an object that is known to both the database thread and the UI thread.
You cancel the query by calling `cancel`.

The effect is documented:

> If the operation is canceled, then `OperationCanceledException` will be thrown when the query is executed.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs lets take contentProvider query method as an example.

> query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[]
>   selectionArgs, String sortOrder, **CancellationSignal
>   cancellationSignal**)

so just make your activity for example implement a cancellationSignalListener like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Actvity implements CancellationSignalListener{...}
```

then create a [CancelationSignal](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/os/CancellationSignal.html). Set it like  :

```
mCancellationSignal.setOnCancelListener(this);
```

pass mCancellationSignal into the contentProvider query method and now you can either force a cancellation or if one occurs internally you will get notified.